# Elliptic Curve Cryptography : sending an encrypted message using NFC in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, cryptography, nfc, elliptic-curve

I'm currently working on an ECC project. So the project goes like this, I want to send an encrypted message from my android phone using NFC to a contactless smart card. The tag is being developed by a different team, so that's not the problem here.

I've already made a program on eclipse to send and receive the message, but I want the message to be encrypted.

The problem is, I'm quite new to android eclipse but I've already read the descriptions on android developers and all of the problems related to ECC on this forum including [Nelenkov's blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-ecdh-on-android.html), but I still can't find a way to send and receive an encrypted message using NFC. Can someone please help me?

If it helps, here is the code I wrote to send the message using NFC:

```
@SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "ParserError" })
public class Daftar extends Activity {
    private NfcAdapter adapter;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    private Tag mytag;
    Context ctx;
    private EditText edNIM, edNama;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daftar);
    edNIM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    edNama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    Button Write = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    crypto = Crypto.getInstance();
    Write.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(mytag==null){ 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }else{  
                    String id = null;
                    String nama = null;
                    if(edNIM.getText()!=null && edNama.getText()!=null)
                    {
                        id = edNIM.getText().toString();
                        nama = edNama.getText().toString();
                    }
                    write(id+"?"+nama,mytag);


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Pengguna Baru" +
                                    "\nNIM = " + id +
                                    "\nNama = " + nama
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent Home = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                            Home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            Home.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(Home);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Penulisan Tag Mengalami Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Penulisan Tag Mengalami Error" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

}


private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}

private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + textLength];

    payload[0] = 0x01;
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 , textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA ,
            "app/bikebdg".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")), 
            new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}   

public void save(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.daftar, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Kartu dapat ditulis" +
                "\nTekan Save untuk menulis kartu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

private void WriteModeOn(){
    writeMode = true;
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
}

private void WriteModeOff(){
    writeMode = false;
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

}
```

Comment: So you want to write an NDEF message with encrypted content?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Can you please help me?

Comment: Try some of the examples in my lib: https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/

Comment: Hi, i've read your example codes. I'm sorry but I can't find the library or codes to encrypt the ndef message.

Comment: You'll be encrypting the contents within the NDEF message, not the message itself. Do the encryption and put the resulting bytes in an external type or 'unknown type' record.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I've tried encrypting the NDEF message, but I can't seem to succeed. Can you give me a few reading materials that relate to ECC encrypting using NFC? Thanks a lot

Comment: NFC and (ECC) encryption are completely unrelated things. So you would just use Android's crypto API to encrypt the payload of your NDEF record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use many Javascript libraries for encryption but i recommend [SJCL](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) because of it's good performance.

> The Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (hosted here on GitHub) is a project by the Stanford Computer Security Lab to build a secure, powerful, fast, small, easy-to-use, cross-browser library for cryptography in Javascript.

You may also use [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) to encrypt and decrypt messages.